# Where can I find research papers on Data Science and AI?

Tags: machine-learning, ai, deep-learning, research-papers

Where can I find a free and open resource of categorized scholarly articles in the fields of Data Science/Machine Learning/Deep Learning/AI/Statistics papers, code, and evaluation tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [PapersWithCode](https://paperswithcode.com/)

[Browse State-of-the-Art](https://paperswithcode.com/sota)

`3,076 benchmarks • 1,689 tasks • 2,719 datasets • 27,765 papers with code`

All data is licensed under the CC BY-SA license, the same as Wikipedia.
The vast majority of the data is either annotated by the community or by them. However, they also included data from other resources that are published under a compatible license, such as NLP-progress, EFF AI metrics, SQuAD, and RedditSota.

---

#### [arXiv.org](https://arxiv.org/)

arXiv is a free distribution service and an open-access archive for 1,757,455 scholarly articles in the fields of physics, mathematics, computer science, quantitative biology, quantitative finance, statistics, electrical engineering and systems science, and economics. Materials on this site are not peer-reviewed by arXiv.